# Joomla redirect 403

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I need to redirect from http://mysite/component/users to main page
i tried this rule in .htaccess but code not working.

```
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule http://mysite/component/users/ index.php [F]
```

but i need to keep from redirecting this page 
http://mysite/component/users/?view=reset

it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things fundamentally wrong with your `RewriteRule`:

- When you use the `F` flag you can't rewrite the URL. The substitution is ignored.
- The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is a regular expression and matches against the URL-path, not the absolute URL.

In order to return a 403 *and* display the appropriate content, you could either:

- Internally rewrite to `index.php` and conditionally return a 403 Forbidden header.

or

- Serve your 403 error document (using the `F` flag) and conditionally show your content?

However, I would simply serve the appropriate 403 error document and *link* to the homepage. The request is after all forbidden....

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^view=reset
RewriteRule ^component/users/ - [F]
```

The above sends a 403 to all requests for URLs that start `/component/users/`, excluding those that have the query string `view=reset`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but not working on my site. maybe it's possible redirect from this url in .htaccess ?